# Возможно ли определить на устройстве программно включен ли режим разработчика?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможно программно, с помощью приложения, определить включен ли режим разработчика на устройстве или нет?

Например какой нибудь запрос возвращающий булевую переменную похожий на android.os.Build.devModeEnable()?

Comment: *Режим разработчика* влияет только на то, видны ли опции для разработчиков. Как по мне - логично, что приложение не может этого узнать. Лучше напишите, чего вы хотите при помощи этого добиться, и вам подскажут более правильный путь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

пробуй это

```
int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

для API 16 можешь юзать так: `Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED`

статьи [одна](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED)  и [вторая](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#pubmethods)